# Have the lowest y-value as the bottom most line

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

So I made a graph using seaborn (and matplotlib using Python) and generated this image as my graph [(link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekwgk.png). I would like to have the 0 y-axis line to be the bottom line in the graph, an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD4NM.png).

Here is my current code if that helps:

```py
sns.reset_defaults()
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(7,5)})
plt.style.use("dark_background")
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Time", y="Messages")
plt.gca().axes.xaxis.grid(False)
plt.fill_between(df.Time.values, df.Messages.values, alpha=0.5)
plt.savefig(f"sentAssets/guild{ctx.guild.id}-{datetime.datetime.now().date()}.png", transparent=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can set the limit of the y-axis from zero to get the desired format. The data and code are used from the [official reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot).

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights.head()

may_flights = flights.query("month == 'May'")
# sns.lineplot(data=may_flights, x="year", y="passengers")

sns.reset_defaults()
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(7,5)})
plt.style.use("dark_background")
sns.lineplot(data=may_flights, x="year", y="passengers")
plt.gca().axes.xaxis.grid(False)
plt.fill_between(may_flights.year.values, may_flights.passengers.values, alpha=0.5)
plt.ylim(0,max(may_flights.passengers))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer